# Finding/Calculating the bend "direction" of a Sheet metal CAD model

Tags: computational-geometry, opencascade

There is this property that I call the bend "direction" that I would like to assign to bend features of a CAD model based on the side in which the acute/obtuse angle of the bend is located. For example, in the diagrams below I use +/- for the assignment.
[image]

Above is the model in question and below is the bend direction assigned to each bend. (+) for the bends whose acute/obtuse angle side is facing same side and (-) otherwise.

[image]

Tried the function:

```
TopAbs_Orientation TopoDS_Shape::Orientation() const
```

But the outputs are not consistent.

Is there a mathematical method/ opencascade function that I can use to determine and assign bend "directions". Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sign of the Gaussian curvature of the cylindrical faces to give you the convexity.

Its worth noting that the bend direction you are trying to define depends on the side of the sheet metal you measure from. All the signs will flip if you look at it from the other side. This is probably why Orientation looked inconsistent.